# Keycloak replies 401 to Angular webapp

Tags: angular, keycloak, http-status-code-401

It's my first time trying to integrate KeyCloak. Here is what I've written in my Angular webapp `app.module.ts` file in order to initialize KeyCloak.js:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { APP_INITIALIZER, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { CalendarModule, DateAdapter } from 'angular-calendar';
import { adapterFactory } from 'angular-calendar/date-adapters/date-fns';
import {NgxPaginationModule} from 'ngx-pagination';
import { NgxGoogleAnalyticsModule } from 'ngx-google-analytics';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment.prod';
import { KeycloakService } from 'keycloak-angular';
import { LoginInfo } from '../main';

const initializeKeycloak = (keycloak: KeycloakService) => async () =>
    keycloak.init({
      config: {
        url: (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('loginInfo')) as LoginInfo).baseUrl,
        realm: (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('loginInfo')) as LoginInfo).realm,
        clientId: (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('loginInfo')) as LoginInfo).client
      },
      initOptions: {
        onLoad: 'check-sso',
        silentCheckSsoRedirectUri:
          window.location.origin + '/assets/silent-check-sso.html'
      },
      shouldAddToken: (request) => {
        const { method, url } = request;

        const isGetRequest = 'GET' === method.toUpperCase();
        const acceptablePaths = ['/assets', '/clients/public'];
        const isAcceptablePathMatch = acceptablePaths.some((path) => url.includes(path));

        return !(isGetRequest && isAcceptablePathMatch);
      }
    });
@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    // eslint-disable-next-line max-len
    imports: [FormsModule, BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule, HttpClientModule, BrowserAnimationsModule, CalendarModule.forRoot({ provide: DateAdapter, useFactory: adapterFactory }), NgxPaginationModule,
        NgxGoogleAnalyticsModule.forRoot(environment.ga4MeasurementId)],
    providers: [KeycloakService,
      {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: initializeKeycloak,
      multi: true,
      deps: [KeycloakService]
    }, { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

this is the referenced `/assets/silent-check-sso.html` file:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script>
      parent.postMessage(location.href, location.origin);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

then I have the `route-guard.service.ts` file:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, CanActivate, RouterStateSnapshot, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { KeycloakAuthGuard, KeycloakService } from 'keycloak-angular';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RouteGuardService extends KeycloakAuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(
    protected readonly router: Router,
    protected readonly keycloak: KeycloakService) {
      super(router, keycloak);
    }

  public async isAccessAllowed(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ) {
    // Force the user to log in if currently unauthenticated.
    if (!this.authenticated) {
      await this.keycloak.login({
        redirectUri: window.location.origin + state.url
      });
    }

    // Get the roles required from the route.
    const requiredRoles = route.data.roles;

    // Allow the user to proceed if no additional roles are required to access the route.
    if (!(requiredRoles instanceof Array) || requiredRoles.length === 0) {
      return true;
    }

    // Allow the user to proceed if all the required roles are present.
    return requiredRoles.every((role) => this.roles.includes(role));
  }
}
```

here is my `app-routing.module.ts` file:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { RouteGuardService } from './guard/route-guard.service';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'prenotazioni',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
  {
    path: 'prenotazioni',
    loadChildren: () => import('./prenotazioni/prenotazioni.module').then( m => m.PrenotazioniPageModule),
    canActivate: [RouteGuardService]
  },
  {
    path: 'agenda',
    loadChildren: () => import('./agenda/agenda.module').then( m => m.AgendaPageModule),
    canActivate: [RouteGuardService]
  },
  {
    path: 'configuratore',
    loadChildren: () => import('./configuratore/configuratore.module').then( m => m.ConfiguratorePageModule),
    canActivate: [RouteGuardService]
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    loadChildren: () => import('./login/login.module').then( m => m.LoginPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'customer-sat-page',
    loadChildren: () => import('./customer-sat-page/customer-sat-page.module').then( m => m.CustomerSatPagePageModule)
  },
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

I took almost everything from online tutorials. TBH, I don't understand 100% of it... Anyway, when I try to browse my webapp, it correctly redirects me to KeyCloak. I can login, but after I'm redirected back to my webapp I only get a blank page. The browser console log shows:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 ()
```

and the failed resource is `https://my.keycloack.domain/realms/myRealm/protocol/openid-connect/token`

KC log shows only:

```
2023-03-03 18:39:00,770 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (executor-thread-62) type=CODE_TO_TOKEN_ERROR, realmId=myRealm, clientId=myClient, userId=null, ipAddress=x.y.z.t, error=invalid_client_credentials, grant_type=authorization_code
```

but I'm sure I entered the correct password.

I've found a few other threads with similar problems (HTTP 401 error), but they all have different solutions that are specific to their configuration. I couldn't find anything that could fit my Angular 15 + KeyCloak 20 setup, nor I could find a way to try those solutions in my case.

Can you please help me understand why KC does not like the token request?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem and the solution.

TLDR: just ditch the whole `initOptions`.

"Long" answer: `silentCheckSsoRedirectUri` does not work anymore in modern browsers, because of limitations on what `<iframe>`s can do with the cookies.  It's documented [here](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#_modern_browsers), though I don't fully understand to what extent it can still work as of today. Anyway, since it's going to stop working sooner or later, I just prefer to opt out now and use tokens only.